# non-removable laptop battery gone bad

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Dell Inspiron 5523 laptop with non-removable battery. It's been about 3 years and the battery is gone bad now. It gives less than half hour of backup. Are non removable batteries non-replaceable for good? Can I somehow change the battery or the life of my laptop is gone if the battery life is gone?

Comment: Given that Dell sell batteries for this laptop one would assume it is replaceable :)

Comment: Appears replaceable, just takes a little bit of time and work, nothing major though. Check this video out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkyvebu8uXQ